# Difference between Panel and Shell window type

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I can not understand, from the official documentation, the exact difference between those two:

> Use the chrome.app.window module to create windows. Windows can either
>   be shells or panels. Shell windows have no browser chrome. **Panel
>   windows are the same as shell windows, except they have different size
>   and position restrictions, for example, a chat panel.**

Which restrictions are they talking about (I have done some testing and I can not say the difference between those two...)? What is a chat panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels are not currently supported. The reference to them in the documentation is a [documentation bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181457). You can see in the [app_window.idl](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/app_window.idl&q=app_window%20panel&sq=package%3achromium&type=cs&l=61) file that the feature is experimental and limited to the aura shell 'ash'.